# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) CHECK constraint failed: vehicle

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm having this error mentioned in the title when I try to insert data on my sqlite database. The data comes from a form in a front-end.

I defined two models of entities, a Person and a Vehicle. They are related in type one(Person) to many(Vehicle). 
I use this models on file controllers.py to insert data on then.

```py
### file models.py
from app import db

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    cpf = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False, unique=True)

    owns = db.relationship('Vehicle')

    def __init__(self, username, password, first_name, last_name, cpf, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.email = email

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(sef):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(sef):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<UsersLogin %r>" % self.username

class Vehicle(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'vehicle'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
        license_plate = db.Column(db.String(20))
        crlv = db.Column(db.String(600))
        crv = db.Column(db.String(600))

        def __init__(self, license_plate, crlv, crv):
            self.license_plate = license_plate
            self.crlv = crlv
            self.crv = crv

### file controllers.py

### codes...

if current_user.is_authenticated:

        person = Person.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
        new_vehicle = Vehicle(
            license_plate=form.license_plate.data,
            crlv=form.crlv.data,
            crv=form.crv.data,
        )

        person.owns.append(new_vehicle)
        db.session.add(new_vehicle)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Congrats! Your vihicle was recorded on our system!")
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

I want to add a new Vehicle to a person, the Person already exists on my database. That's the problem. When I try do that, I'm having the error below:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) CHECK constraint failed: vehicle
>   [SQL: INSERT INTO vehicle (person_id, license_plate, crlv, crv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
>   [parameters: (2, '4', '3', '4')]

The data comes from the front-end.

Please, anyone can help me to stop this error on my code?

Comment: I think this may be happening due to the duplicate fk insertion? Try the insertion with clean database and block the same fk from entering into DB twice.